# iPhone 4 is unable to connect to 3G network

Tags: network, iphone, cellular-data

I am now unable to connect to a network to be able to use our internet provider or any other provider. It just keeps "looking" for a network however network options never appear. Despite manually asking to join a network we are still denied access to join despite entering in the correct network data and passcode. The phone is however capable of getting wi-fi but just exhausts all of our data on our plan. Any help to resolve this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: iPhone 4 is fairly old. Have you considered getting a new device.

Comment: Age shouldn't matter here :-) Sara, this sounds more like an issue with your SIM card or your mobile plan, might be best to check with the carrier.

Answer (score -1):

Will better to do that issue is you need to try reset your network settings and its automaticaly regenarated from your network carrier..  Try it.. Maybe its work from your problem.